# Lambda times out after ending

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

After finishing successfully, a Lambda function insists on timing out.

The function's triggering event is `s3:ObjectCreated:*`.

The function uses MongoDB Atlas and does so according to the optimisation suggestions on https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-aws-lambda-performance-with-mongodb-atlas-and-nodejs, including setting: 
`context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;` before using the DB.

The function also calls some AWS SDK methods with successfully resolved promises.

After finishing my code successfully and doing everything it set out to do, I get the following in my CloudWatch logs, (both the request's END event *and* its timeout):

```
START RequestId: XXX    
... my logs...
END RequestId: XXX
REPORT RequestId: XXX   Duration: 6001.12 ms    Billed Duration: 6000 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB   Max Memory Used: 49 MB  
XXX Task timed out after 6.00 seconds
```

The function then repeats itself twice more with the same unfortunate result.

Any immediate suspects? Where should I look?

Comment: Can you include your handler code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `callback(null, <any>)` in order to end your function handler and tell Lambda that your function executed successfully.

Without that, Lambda will retry the same invocation after a delay and it will again finish but without telling Lambda that it finished successfully.

Comment: Oddly this did the trick. Why is this necessary even though I don't require a return value from the function? [According to AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html) calling callback() is the same as calling nothing at all, which is signalling that the function ended successfully without returning a result.

Comment: It is necessary because that is how the calling function (which is invisible to us) behaves.